# What is the difference between によると and によりますと?

Tags: word-choice, politeness

What is the difference between **Aによると、B。**　and 　**Aによりますと、B。**?

In the texts I'm refering to both structures seem to mean 'According to A, it is B'. However, the first was used in simplified articles, whereas the second was used in the original articles. So, is it just the case that the second one is used in more formal situations than the first one or is there something else to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is just whether it's polite or not. There is nothing more than that.

よりますと is politer than よると.